# Javascript regular expression to match at least a special character within any string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a regular expression which contains any letter and or number, but it has to contains at least one special character, that is to say an *,!@#$%^&*()_=

I have this:

```js
let value = 'ABC*123';
let result = value.match(new RegExp('^.*[\W]+.*$'));

console.log(result);
```

which, according to https://www.debuggex.com/#cheatsheet is a well written regular expression, but this continues returning null. What am I missing here?

Comment: `"\W"` = `"W"` = `W` is plain text. You need `"\\W"`. Use `/\W/.test(value)`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew... you are right!

Comment: FYI, `\W` also matches spaces. If you do not consider spaces special, use `/[^\w\s]/` or `/[^\w ]/`.